# Cursor Loader observer already registered error

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my application, and I am loading the data with `CursorLoader`. Apparently there is some problem with the loading of data using this approach, because from time to time I keep getting this error:

```
07-01 11:17:49.209: E/AndroidRuntime(20758): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer
android.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver@422dd8b8 is already registered.
```

Did anyone have this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have solved the problem. I had this kind of crash (error) only when I performed on item clicks from the autocomplete list from the `AutoCompleteTextView`. The error was obviously internal, and it had something to do with the inner observer of the CursorAdapter that I had been using as an `Adapter` for my `AutoCompleteTextView`. So now, on every item click, I do the following:

```
    txtAutocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // ... your code here ...
                autocompleteContactsAdapter.changeCursor(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now my application does not crash.